# Integrate 2D Gaussian over a segment

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I have the following 2D Gaussian:

```
{m[r_, t_], Sigma[S11_,S22_,p_]} := {{r Cos[t],r Sin[t]},{{S11,p S11 S22},{p S11 S22,S22}}};
h[r_, t_, S11_, S22_, p_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[m[r, t], Sigma[S11, S22, p]], {x, y}]
```

I want to integrate this 2D Gaussian of the `x y` region between the lines `y = Tan[\[Pi]/8] x` and `y = Tan[3\[Pi]/8] x`. Specifically, I want to find:

```
Integrate[h[r, \[Pi]/8, s, s, 0], , {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, Tan[\[Pi]/8] x, Tan[3 \[Pi]/8]  x}];
```

How can I recast the problem so that I get a result from this?

Comment: There were comments to this question (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueebu4kh7ncyxt8/screen17.01.20.docx?dl=0) . I don't understand why those were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Likely no chance. Even `Integrate[ h[1, \ [Pi]/8, 2, 2, 0], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, Tan[\[Pi]/8] x], Tan[3 \[Pi]/8] x}]` performs only the result of the integration by `y` from `Tan[\[Pi]/8] x` to `Tan[3 \ [Pi]/8] x` . I think the integral under consideration can be taken only numerically as a function of the parameters `r` and `s`:

```
f[r_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[h[r, \[Pi]/8, s, s, 0], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
{y, Tan[\[Pi]/8] x, Tan[3 \[Pi]/8] x}]
Plot3D[f[r, s], {r, 0, 2}, {s, 0.01, 2}]
```

[image]